# jQuery images do not fade in

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of image URLs in JSON that I am using to put a bunch of images in a div. They start out with opacity 0 and they are supposed to fade in with a for loop.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$.ajax('http://thesabreslicer.site.nfoservers.com/thesabreslicer/dw/json/imgs.json').done(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var image = data[i];
        $('#imgs').append('<img src="' + image.url + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left; padding:5px;opacity:0;">');
    }
    var imgs = $('#imgs > img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        if (imgs.eq(i).css('opacity') === 0) {
            imgs.eq(i).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the HTML div:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Technologies We Use</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="imgs" class="col-md-12">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you define your problem more clearly?

Comment: Off topic: You have nested columns without the required row between.

Comment: @SirNeuman the images do not fade in when they are supposed to

Comment: please be aware that your directory at `http://thesabreslicer.site.nfoservers.com/thesabreslicer/dw/json/` is opening in directory and any file can be seen then(also your server type, Port ...) use .htaccess and `deny to all` to avoid this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things here. First off, make sure that you are not trying to use AJAX across different domains or it can get blocked.

Secondly, there is no need for two loops. I would combine it like I have below:

```
$.ajax('http://thesabreslicer.site.nfoservers.com/thesabreslicer/dw/json/imgs.json').done(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var image = data[i];
        var newImg = $('<img src="' + image.url + '" class="img-responsive" style="float:left; padding:5px;opacity:0;" />');
        $('#imgs').append(newImg);
        newImg.animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

One other thing to not is that you are using 1000 (1 second), so its hard to see. Change that to something higher to see better results.

You may also want to check that the image is loaded before you fade as well. You could do something like:

```
newImg.load(function(){
   newImg.animate({
      'opacity': '1'
   }, 1000);
});
```